# How to merge two arrays of same size into an array of tuples with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, tuples

I have a project in python where I want to get a 2D matrix filled with coordinates:

First, I use the meshgrid function to get my coordinates in 2 arrays:

`X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))`

I get:

```
X =   0 1 2 3 4        Y =   0 0 0 0 0
      0 1 2 3 4              1 1 1 1 1
      0 1 2 3 4              2 2 2 2 2
      0 1 2 3 4              3 3 3 3 3
      0 1 2 3 4              4 4 4 4 4
```

Now, I'd like to merge the two arrays into a single array of tuples like this:

```
Coordinates = (0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) 
              (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (4,1) 
              (0,2) (1,2) (2,2) (3,2) (4,2) 
              (0,3) (1,3) (2,3) (3,3) (4,3) 
              (0,4) (1,4) (2,4) (3,4) (4,4)
```

And I want to create a really big matrix, like 10 000 x 10 000 , so it has to be really fast (as fast as 
possible in fact) ...

Comment: Nice ! Thank you

Comment: Would you be happy with a 3d array, with the last dimension of 2?

Comment: ```np.dstack((X,Y))``` would work in this case.

Comment: `X + 1j*Y` makes a 2d array of complex numbers.

Comment: @hpaulj Perfect !

Comment: Thank you for your answers !
Finally, I found a simpler way by using complex numbers:

    `X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))
    matrix = X + Y * 1j`

What I get:

   `[[0.+0.j 1.+0.j 2.+0.j 3.+0.j 4.+0.j]
    [0.+1.j 1.+1.j 2.+1.j 3.+1.j 4.+1.j]
    [0.+2.j 1.+2.j 2.+2.j 3.+2.j 4.+2.j]
    [0.+3.j 1.+3.j 2.+3.j 3.+3.j 4.+3.j]
    [0.+4.j 1.+4.j 2.+4.j 3.+4.j 4.+4.j]] `